# Remove multisite "blog" slug from specific custom post type

Tags: permalinks

I have wordpress multisite, by default multisite has the word "blog" added to all post types excluding "pages" How would i only remove it from a specific custom post type.

If I go to setting and remove the "blog slug" from setting it gets remove from the actual blog section of the website which i don't want because i need to keep the URL the same.

Answer (score 2):

Set `with_front` to `false` to not prepended the front base to the permalink structure. Customize the permalink structure via the `slug`:

```
'rewrite' => array( 
    'with_front' => false, 
    'slug' => 'portfolio'
)
```

Comment: Setting "with_front" to false when setting up a custom post will remove the "blog" slug from the post type url.

Comment: Add this to your answer, thanks! And additionally add that the parameter `rewrite` is part off your `register_post_type` call.